# How to complete missing character in a column of Python Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
d = {'col1': ["1", "2", "3", "4"], 'col2': ["5%", "6", "7%", "8%"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

   col1  col2
0     1    5%
1     2     6
2     3    7%
3     4    8%
```

In some rows of `col2`, there can be numbers without a **%** sign at the end. And I do not know in advance in which rows I have this problem. I need to make sure that all numbers have the % sign in `col2`.

Is there a way to do it in Python without looping through the DataFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [numpy where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
df["col2"] = np.where(df.col2.str.endswith("%"), df.col2, df.col2.add("%"))

        col1    col2
    0   1       5%
    1   2       6%
    2   3       7%
   3    4       8%
```

Alternatively, you could use a `list comprehension` - they are quite effective, especially with strings :

```
df['col2'] = [f"{entry}%" if not entry.endswith("%") else entry 
              for entry in df.col2]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
condition=[df.col2.str.contains('%'),~df.col2.str.contains('%')]
choices=[df.col2, df.col2 +"%"]
df.col2=np.select(condition,choices)

  col1 col2
0    1   5%
1    2   6%
2    3   7%
3    4   8%
```

Answer (score 1):

similar to sammywemmy's answer. `np.where()` is usually the top option for me in this situation:

```
df['col2'] = np.where(~(df['col2'].str.contains('%')), df['col2'] + '%', df['col2'])
```

OR

```
df['col2'] = np.where((df['col2'].str.contains('%')), df['col2'], df['col2'] + '%')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `'%'` symbol(s) if they exist to the right, then add one back everywhere.

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.rstrip('%')+'%'
```